jest-dom installed but @testing-library looking for dom
I installed jest, jest-environment-jsdom, @testing-library/react and @testing-library/jest-dom, as suggested on the Next.js site.
However, I am unable to run any test that involves working with the DOM, for example:
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

Here's the error I got:
Cannot find module '@testing-library/dom' from 'node_modules/@testing-library/react/`
`dist/pure.js'

I'm pretty sure that I installed jest-dom rather than dom (under the @testing-library scope). When I dig into pure.js of @testing-library/react, on line 46 it's indeed looking for dom:
var _dom = require("@testing-library/dom");

Why is this the case? Did I install anything wrong? Is the documentation incorrect/incomplete?

Did you try installing what it asks for? Yes you installed .../jest-dom, but not .../dom. Note https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/releases/tag/v16.0.0. Next.js docs look out-of-date.

Thanks for responding. I did and it worked, but I'm concerned with why the issue exists, rather than writing things I'm not entirely sure about. I think you are right; the docs is out-of-date. I'll help change it.

Thanks to @jonrsharpe, I'm posting an answer for reference.
According to https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/releases/tag/v16.0.0, testing-library changed dom into a peer dependency about 3 weeks ago at the time of writing, which means it should be installed. The next.js docs should be updated, and I'll try to create a pull request.
